How can I make an alternative, cheaper refrigerator thermostat work?
I have Frigidaire fridge and its thermostat is gone bad. Thermostat part number is 240383703. I ended up buying another thermostat that's much cheaper (part number 2198202).
Now the original thermostat had 4 wire, red, black, purple and green. This new one seems to have only 3 wire. Is it possible to use as a replacement? How do I connect to new thermostat?
Thanks.

Without wiring diagrams for both thermostats and the fridge, it would be nearly impossible to say how to do it. The part you bought is not listed as a replacement for the one you need and has a different number of terminals. Get back with the place you bought it from and get the right part or Google the correct part number and look for a replacement... but those are pretty high too. Sometimes you just have to bite the bullet and pay the higher price. Using a hack part can cause much more expensive damage.

that is the proper way of doing it, but paying 350 for thermostat is waste of money, I may as well just buy new fridge, but throwing away existing one just for a single thermostat is also a waste, that is why I am taking chances. In the worst case I get new fridge. Where would I find the diagramm for them? I spent good amount of time online without any luck. Would be helpful if you can help me find these. Thank you!

I agree with your sentiment, but you're now in the realm of appliance engineering, which is a bit outside the scope of DIY home improvement. You also haven't provided enough information for us to help in the first place. We don't even know what fridge you have.

@lkqWRHL23O no one is talking about paying 350 for a thermostat.  They are talking about going back to the place that sold you the wrong thermostat for $12.99 and getting them to sell you the right thermostat for $12.99. or gosh, maybe $15.

Yeah, so right thermostat is 350. that is why we are talking about alternative option.
